# Cell dropdown list option depends on delimiter string of a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, delimiter

I have "Choices" column which stores the choices of test question.

If the text in "Choices cell" is seperated by delimiter "|||" as follows:
Apple|||Orange|||Banana|||Guava|||

Here it means there are 4 Choices.

I have another column "correct answer" which is a drop down list that let user input the correct answer.

I like to make it depends on the the number of choices.

In this example, the cell of the same row will show 4 options, that are A, B, C and D.

Any formula that can acheive this? Can someone teach me on how to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-C8DE19AE-DD79-4B9B-A14E-B4D906D11B66) function inside of data validation to achieve this.  In particular you need the below function.

```
=OFFSET($I$2, 0, 0, (LEN(A2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "|||", "")))/3)
```

[image]

What I did was create a list of all the possible letters in column I.  The OFFSET function lets you dynamically create a range.  So the above function is saying: Start on cell I2, then go down the required number of space.  The required number of spaces is determine by replacing "|||" with "" then comparing the length of those two strings and dividing by 3.  That will tell you the number of choices.

[image: Sample1]
[image: Sample2]

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly. Thanks so much for your answer!